# How to download all PDF files linked from a single page using wget

Tags: command-line, wget, download

I need to download all PDF files that are linked from this webpage https://www.in.tum.de/i07/lehre/ss22/theo/.

Everything I have tried so far either does not get the files or downloads the **entire** website recursively.

I however am only interested in the PDFs linked to directly from this PAGE (not website).

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `wget`'s `--no-parent` (`-np`) and `--level=depth` (`-l`) options to control how much of the site will be mirrored by the `-r` option.  The `--no-host-directories` (`-nH`) and `--no-directories` (`-nd`) options will also prevent wget from duplicating the remote directory structure.
*(Double hyphen precedes options when they are written in full, , while single hyphen precedes options when they are written in short form --no-parent is -np)*

e.g. something like this:

```
wget -r -l 1 -nH -nd -np --ignore-case -A '*.pdf' https://www.in.tum.de/i07/lehre/ss22/theo/
```

By default, that will save the .pdf files in the current directory.  You can use the `-P` option to specify a different output dir.

`wget` is very flexible and has a lot of options - so many that the man page can be overwhelming when you first read it, but it is definitely worth putting in some effort to read and experiment with.

Answer (score 2):

You can extract the list of PDF files from the web page using `wget` or `curl` to download it, and `xmlstarlet` to parse the resulting HTML/XML:

```
curl https://www.in.tum.de/i07/lehre/ss22/theo/ |
    xmlstarlet format -H index.html 2>/dev/null |
    xmlstarlet select -t -m '//a[contains(@href,"pdf")]' -v '@href' -n
```

The first `xmlstarlet` converts HTML to XML. The second one find all the `a` elements and extracts each `href` attribute value that contains `pdf`.

From there it's straightforward to download each of the extracted links. Pipe the output of the preceding block into a loop

```
while IFS= read -r url
do
    file="${url%\?*}"                            # Strip trailing ? parameters
    file="${file##*/}"                           # Strip leading URL path
    printf "Saving %s as %s\n" "$url" "$file"    # Report action
    curl "$url" >"$file"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

More broadly, You can use wget to download all PDFs from a webpage by using:

```
wget -r -l1 -H -t1 -nd -N -np -A.pdf -erobots=off --wait=2 --random-wait --limit-rate=20k [URL]
```

- -r: Recursive download.
- -l1: Only one level deep (i.e., only files directly linked from this page).
- -H: Span hosts (follow links to other hosts).
- -t1: Number of retries is 1.
- -nd: Don't create a directory structure, just download all the files into the current directory.
- -N: Turn on timestamping.
- -np: Do not follow links to parent directories.
- -A.pdf: Accept only files that end with .pdf.
- -erobots=off: Ignore the robots.txt file (use carefully, respecting site's terms and conditions).
- --wait=2: Wait 2 seconds between each retrieval.
- --random-wait: Wait from 0.5 to 1.5 * --wait seconds between retrievals.
- --limit-rate=20k: Limit the download rate to 20 kilobytes per second.

This parameters will avoid the "429: Too Many Requests" error.